# form filling in my website using google assistant

Tags: android, android-intent, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am new to the Google Assistant. I want to fill a form in my website using the Google Assistant.

When I say, Google Assistant should open the website, ask the mandatory form field values, and submit after confirmation.

Is this possible, and how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Not the way you're describing, no.

There is nothing automatic or built-into the Google Assistant that will open websites and access forms.

You can [write your own Action](https://developers.google.com/actions/) that will open a website to get the form fields and prompt, one by one, for the questions in the form. This wouldn't be terribly usable by your users, however.

Better would be to use Actions on Google to create an Action that has a conversation with the user to get the same information, and then submit it to your server.

Comment: how to collect to answers and submit the answers to the website

Comment: I have to use template or own action ? I want to get form values from user

Comment: You will have to use your own action. The details of doing so are beyond a simple answer - check out the link I provided and, if you have specific questions, ask them as a new StackOverflow question.